# Error on building the retrieval index in Tensorflow Recommenders

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using BruteForce from Tensorflow Recommenders

```
index = tfrs.layers.factorized_top_k.BruteForce(model.customer_model, k = 400)
```

the candidates dataset looks like this:

```
<ZipDataset element_spec=({'article_id': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None), 'prod_name': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None), 'product_type_name': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None)}, TensorSpec(shape=(None, 64), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
```

but when i try to build the retrievel index

```
index.index_from_dataset(candidates)
```

i get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [28], in <cell line: 6>()
      4 candidates = tf.data.Dataset.zip((articles.batch(128), articles.batch(128).map(model.article_model)))
      5 print(candidates)
----> 6 index.index_from_dataset(candidates)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_recommenders/layers/factorized_top_k.py:197, in TopK.index_from_dataset(self, candidates)
    174 def index_from_dataset(
    175     self,
    176     candidates: tf.data.Dataset
    177 ) -> "TopK":
    178   """Builds the retrieval index.
    179 
    180   When called multiple times the existing index will be dropped and a new one
   (...)
    194     ValueError if the dataset does not have the correct structure.
    195   """
--> 197   _check_candidates_with_identifiers(candidates)
    199   spec = candidates.element_spec
    201   if isinstance(spec, tuple):

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_recommenders/layers/factorized_top_k.py:127, in _check_candidates_with_identifiers(candidates)
    119   raise ValueError(
    120       "The dataset must yield candidate embeddings or "
    121       "tuples of (candidate identifiers, candidate embeddings). "
    122       f"Got {spec} instead."
    123   )
    125 identifiers_spec, candidates_spec = spec
--> 127 if candidates_spec.shape[0] != identifiers_spec.shape[0]:
    128   raise ValueError(
    129       "Candidates and identifiers have to have the same batch dimension. "
    130       f"Got {candidates_spec.shape[0]} and {identifiers_spec.shape[0]}."
    131   )

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I assume it has a problem with my dataset which is created from a dictionary.

How should i pass the candidates Dataset so i don't get the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out
i was building the candidates dataset like so:

```
candidates = tf.data.Dataset.zip(articles.batch(128).map(model.article_model)))
index.index_from_dataset(candidates)
```

But i needed to also pass the candidate identifiers, not just candidates embeddings:

```
candidates = tf.data.Dataset.zip((articles.batch(128).map(lambda x: x["article_id"]), articles.batch(128).map(model.article_model)))
index.index_from_dataset(candidates)
```